# Retrieve element from list in hive

Tags: flutter, hive

I have a list in hive of events each with an eventId field. In order to retrieve a specific event, I can retrieve the list from hive and do this to get the one I want.

```
var hiveEvents = HiveEvents.getAllEvents();
var ev = hiveEvents.firstWhere((event) => event.eventId == 8);
```

Is there a better way to pull just the event out of hive by passing the id, or is this the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written in the [docs](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/best-practices/modelling_data?id=modelling-data):

> Hive does not have a query language and only has limited support for sorting, which is not necessarily a disadvantage, as you can see in the benchmark. Sorting and filtering are much faster if you do it yourself in Dart.

So getting the list and using `List` methods is the way to do that in Hive.

If you need to be able to query your data, you can use [Isar](https://isar.dev/) which is a package from the same developer.

Comment: Thank you for your help on a few questions. I will look at Isar when I feel a bit more competent.